# Jquery button don't append elements with no errors at the console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, clone

I have this html form:

```
         <div class="col-sm-4 rounded" style="background-color: #D3D3D3">
          <div class="row clonedInput" id="clonedInput1">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
              <label for="diagnosis_data">Medication</label>
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                  <select class="form-control select" name="diagnosis_data" id="diagnosis_data">
                    <option value="choose">Select</option>
                  </select>
                </fieldset>
            <!-- End class="col-sm-6" -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <label for="patient_weight">Quantity</label>
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="patient_weight" id="patient_weight">
                </fieldset>
            <!-- End class="col-sm-6" -->
            </div>
            <!-- End class="col-sm-6" -->
          </div>
          <div class="actions pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-danger clone">Add More</button> 
            <button class="btn btn-danger remove">Remove</button>
          </div>
```

And this jQuery Script from [this link here](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/tfFLt/):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $("button.clone").on("click", clone);

    $("button.remove").on("click", remove);
  })
    var regex = /^(.+?)(\d+)$/i;
    var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length;
    function clone(){
        $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone()
            .appendTo(".rounded")
            .attr("id", "clonedInput" +  cloneIndex)
            .find("*")
            .each(function() {
                var id = this.id || "";
                var match = id.match(regex) || [];
                if (match.length == 3) {
                    this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
                }
            })
            .on('click', 'button.clone', clone)
            .on('click', 'button.remove', remove);
        cloneIndex++;
    }
    function remove(){
        $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
    }

  </script>
```

But of course with changes to html but nothing happens when I click on each of the buttons, even no errors at the console. Here is [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9L4k8mL/).

I am using jQuery 3.2.1

**EDIT 1**

I tried this script:

```
$("button.clone").on("click", function()
{
   $('.clonedInput').clone().insertAfter('.clonedInput')
});
```

it works but there is 2 problems:

1. ID of each element is not incrementing;
2. If I had 2 elements and clicked on the button they will be 4, then 8, then...

**EDIT 2**

I tried this and the problem number 2 is gone:

```
$("button.clone").on("click", function()
{
  $('#clonedInput1').clone().insertAfter('#clonedInput1')
});
```

Now I still have to increment the id so I can send the data later using Ajax. [Here is my updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9L4k8mL/1/).

Comment: First, you have used #clone where as you have specified class for the add class as clone. secondly, clone is already a predefined function and you are using it as class?There are lot of unused classes.

Comment: @HemaNandagopal see my edit. I don't know why someone downvoted me

Comment: Just now saw your edit.I think your fiddle needs an update? It is not working.Some time people downvote. It happens,Don't worry.

Comment: Please see my edit in 30 seconds and then I will re-update the fiddle

Comment: see **EDIT2** please and the updated fiddle

Comment: Checking out :)

Comment: Would you consider hyphenating your id's? Ie. clonedInput-1, category-1 etc

Comment: yes i could consider that

Comment: console was not giving any error because there was no problem in the javascript code, the problem was in HTML, you were missing one closing div and one div was at the wrong place [jsfiddle for the same](https://jsfiddle.net/Babbandeep/b9L4k8mL/3/)

Comment: The problem is to add only the text boxes and not all the div elements

Answer (score 1):

Check if below code works!

```js
$(document).ready(function()
  {
    $("button.clone").on("click", clone);

    $("button.remove").on("click", remove);
  })
    var regex = /^(.+?)(\d+)$/i;
    var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length;
    function clone(){
    
        $(this).closest(".rounded").clone()
            .insertAfter(".rounded:last")
            .attr("id", "rounded" +  (cloneIndex+1))
            .find("*")
            .each(function() {
                var id = this.id || "";
                var match = id.match(regex) || [];
                if (match.length == 3) {
                    this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex+1);
                }
            })
            .on('click', 'button.clone', clone)
            .on('click', 'button.remove', remove);
        cloneIndex++;
    }
    function remove(){
        $(this).parent().parent(".rounded").remove();
    }
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4 rounded" style="background-color: #D3D3D3">
              <div class="row clonedInput" id="clonedInput1">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label for="diagnosis_data">Medication</label>
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                      <select class="form-control select" name="diagnosis_data" id="diagnosis_data">
                        <option value="choose">Select</option>
                      </select>
                    </fieldset>
                <!-- End class="col-sm-6" -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label for="patient_weight">Quantity</label>
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="patient_weight" id="patient_weight">
                    </fieldset>
                <!-- End class="col-sm-6" -->
                </div>
                <!-- End class="col-sm-6" -->
              </div>
              <div class="actions pull-right">
                <button class="btn btn-danger clone">Add More</button> 
                <button class="btn btn-danger remove">Remove</button>
              </div>
```

Comment: It is adding 2 div at each time

Comment: The problem is to add only the text boxes and not all the div elements

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to hyphenating the id's:

```js
var regex = /^(.+?)(\d+)$/i;
var cloneIndex = 1;

function clone(){
  cloneIndex++;
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone()
        .appendTo("body")
        .attr("id", 'clonedInput-'+(cloneIndex))
        .find("*")
        .each(function() {
            var id = this.id || "";
            var match = id.match(regex) || [];
            if (match.length == 3) {
                this.id = id.split('-')[0] +'-'+(cloneIndex);
            }
        })
        .on('click', 'button.clone', clone)
        .on('click', 'button.remove', remove);
}
function remove(){
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
}
$("button.clone").on("click", clone);

$("button.remove").on("click", remove);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clonedInput-1" class="clonedInput">
    <div>
        <label for="txtCategory" class="">Learning category <span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
        <select class="" name="txtCategory[]" id="category-1">
            <option value="">Please select</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="txtSubCategory" class="">Sub-category <span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
        <select class="" name="txtSubCategory[]" id="subcategory-1">
            <option value="">Please select category</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="txtSubSubCategory">Sub-sub-category <span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
        <select name="txtSubSubCategory[]" id="subsubcategory-1">
            <option value="">Please select sub-category</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <button class="clone">Clone</button> 
        <button class="remove">Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And then I can send all data via array using Ajax to PHP ?

Comment: Yeah as long as this is all within a form with a submit button, you shouldn't have a problem passing the data to PHP

Comment: But it is adding 2 divs at each time

Comment: Doesn't seem to be for me, have you tested it on StackOverflow by pressing "Run code snippet"?

Comment: The problem is to add only the text boxes and not all the div elements

Comment: But you need the parent div so that you can remove it if you need to, you're already duplicating it in your original code also

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the parent `div`. As you are doing in `clone()` : 
`$(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone()`

But in your html `<div class="clonedInput" id="clonedInput1">` is not parent of `<button class="btn btn-danger clone">Add More</button>`.

Here is the updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/b9L4k8mL/2/

Comment: The problem is to add only the text boxes and not all the div elements